# Doctrine2 @Version annotation in yaml file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml

I want to use doctrine versionable in my project. In annotation mapping it looks like this:

```
/*
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Version
 */
private $version;
```

I use yaml - what I must white in my code? I have:

```
SMS\MyBundle\Wykbadpoz:
    type: entity
    table: wykbadpoz
    fields:
        version: 
            type: integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got into the same problem today and solution that you are looking for is:

```
SMS\MyBundle\Wykbadpoz:
    type: entity
    table: wykbadpoz
    fields:
        version: 
            type: integer
            version:
                type: integer
                default: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using the wrong annotations, use the `Loggable` extension. Take a look at the extension docs for more info: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md

So, the entity should be tagged with `@Gedmo\Loggable` and the attribute should be tagged with `@Gedmo\Versioned`. Also don't forget to import the annotations:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
```

You can make use of the [`StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle`](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to easen activating the extensions.